# Problemas con el método SetFocus

Tags: windows-forms, vba, ms-access

Al iniciar un formulario de Access, llamo al constructor del formulario en VBA, que tiene el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Frases As New ETiposFrase   'Objeto Frases
Set Carga = New CCargar         'Objeto Carga
'Constructor del Formulario I
With Me
    .TbFrase.SetFocus
    .TbFrase.Text = Carga.FraseDelDia(IdTipoFrase:=Frases.Generales)
End With
'Constructor del Formulario II
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize
```

Sin embargo el evento setfouc genera un eror, ¿alguien sabe porqué?

Comment: ¿Qué error?¿En qué momento?¿Qué se supone que debería pasar?¿Hay datos en el recordet?¿El control está bloqueado o no visible? ¿Qué has intentado para arreglarlo y que no funciona? ¿De verdad necesitas el Setfocus ahí? ¿Qué tipo de control es `TbFrase`?Lee [Método Control.SetFocus (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.control.setfocus) y [Evento Form.Open (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.form.open)

Comment: El problema que estás experimentando es debido a cómo funciona el método SetFocus en Access VBA. No puedes mover el foco a un control hasta que el evento Load del formulario haya terminado. Debes usar el método Docmd.Repaint antes del método SetFocus